# Passing value from Nullable Date Time to Date Time variable in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

In my ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework application, I created my database table column `Approved_Date` as nullable.

```
public DateTime? Approved_Date { get; set; }
```

Then when I calling data to the report I created a view model and created property as,

```
public DateTime ApprovedDateDM { get; set; }
```

In the query I cannot assign the `Approved_Date` value from the database table to the view model `ApprovedDateDM`. I'm getting an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'type1' to 'type2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
select new SuspensApprovedList {
     ApprovedDateDM = pa.Approved_Date, //Error
     ApprovedDateFM = se.FinanceApprovedDate, //Error
     ApproverDM = ae.EmpName,
     ApproverDessignationDM = ad.Designation,
     ApproverDessignationFM = d.Designation,
     ApproverFM = fe.EmpName,
}).ToList();
```

I could simply change the view model property to nullable and fix the issue, but when I pass this view model data to the Crystal Report I getting another error that Crystal Report won't allow nullable values.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: So, why is your DB column nullable? What does it mean to have a null date? "The application is not approved"? If crystal doesn't allow it you will have to pass this same thing you mean in another way, for example, pass DateTime.MinValue and then crystal can look and see if the date is 0000-01-01 and write "Not Approved" else put the date

Comment: @CaiusJard If I change the view model property to nullable, in the report load I get ``DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.`` error. Why the Datetime is nullable, that is it only get updated when request got approved by the user. That is the reason I put it as nullable.

Comment: So.. Any thoughts on the other part of my comment? The part where I pointed out that if crystal cannot accept the nullable then you have to convey the "the request is not approved" in another way? Like passing DateTime.MinValue or passing a separate bool IsApproved? Imagine - what would you do if C# didn't have null, if Nullable wasn't a thing. That's the world you say Crystal is, so you have to invent a solution for that

Comment: Show us how the value is used in the Crystal Report and tell us what you want the report to show for a request that is not approved. Also add a tag for the version of crystal you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 select new SuspensApprovedList {
     ApprovedDateDM = pa.Approved_Date.HasValue?pa.Approved_Date : DateTime.MinValue, //or any default value you prefer.
     ApprovedDateFM = pa.FinanceApprovedDate.HasValue?pa.FinanceApprovedDate: DateTime.MinValue,
     ApproverDM = ae.EmpName,
     ApproverDessignationDM = ad.Designation,
     ApproverDessignationFM = d.Designation,
     ApproverFM = fe.EmpName,

 }).ToList();
```

Or you can use

```
 select new SuspensApprovedList {
     ApprovedDateDM = pa.Approved_Date.GetValueOrDefault(), // You can pass the default value also like GetValueOrDefault(defaultDate)
     ApprovedDateFM = pa.FinanceApprovedDate.GetValueOrDefault(),
     ApproverDM = ae.EmpName,
     ApproverDessignationDM = ad.Designation,
     ApproverDessignationFM = d.Designation,
     ApproverFM = fe.EmpName,

 }).ToList();
```

Comment: DateTime.Min is not a thing. Please address the actual issue of what then to do with the value inside of Crystal Reports, which is the true issue here

Answer (score 0):

You can also use null-coalescing operator (??=  or ?? ) which will return the value if it is not null, or return the value to the right of the operator

If you want to return current datetime in case nullable one is null, you can use the following

ApprovedDateDM = Approved_Date ?? DateTime.Now